# WiFi range problem (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: wireless, atheros

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10  to dual-boot with windows. While WiFi is completly fine on Windows and I can access it anywhere in my house, it's absolutety not the case on Ubuntu. As soon as I'm not near my router, the WiFi is out of range and I can't select it anymore. The only times it worked, it lost connection <1 minute later.

My Wifi card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9285, if necessary.

Any help would be appreciated a lot, thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. My wi-fi works great in Windows 8 but when it comes to Ubuntu I can't get the signal in the same place I use it on Windows. I think I will try Mint or another distro...

Comment: I had the same issue, and solved it, as it is explained here http://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices